# React app my components are not popping up as a jsx

Tags: reactjs

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgR98.png)

When I create a React app, before my components used to turn like a turquoise green. Now it doesnt also im seeing so many red as well as errors. Im following a React portfolio tutorial step by step, but not sure if my app is working properly. Maybe I need to fix it with an npm package?

Comment: I noticed a typo in your route tag, the property should be `element=` not `elment=`. Not sure if that is the cause for the visual bug though.

Comment: Have you made sure you read it? https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview

Answer (score 0):

Try to install `react-router-dom`

And restart your `vscode`

Then `Run your app again`, the Router tags should be Green the same like components

Comment: Thank you will, try, I’m new new bootcamp grad trying to hone my skills in the dev game . I heard Stackoverflow is one of the biggest helpers out there